# Random walk in one dimension with different probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

As the title suggests, I'm concerned with a typical random walk problem, where the probability to go right is $p$ and the probability to go left is $q=1-p$. I was trying to find the probability of reaching a position $ml$ (where l is the length of each step) and prove that the sum of all the probabilities across m is 1. The first part was fairly trivial, but I can't figure out how to do the second part in a reasonable way.

The variables I used are

$m = N_r - N_l$ (number of steps left and right)

and

N = total number of steps

For the first part I got P = $\frac{N!}{\frac{N+m}{2}!\frac{N-m}{2}!} p^{\frac {N + m}2}(1-p)^{\frac {N - m}2}$

I'm not sure how to reasonably integrate this to show that the total probability is 1. I used Stirling's approximation and got $\ln \sqrt{2\pi n}(\frac n e)^n - \ln \sqrt{2\pi(n+m)/2}(\frac{n+m}{2e})^{\frac{n+m}{2}}-\ln \sqrt{2\pi(n-m)/2}(\frac{n-m}{2e})^{\frac{n-m}{2}} + \ln(p^{\frac{n+m}{2}})+\ln((1-p)^{\frac{n-m}{2}}$

Which I can't reasonably integrate. Come to think of it I've realized there is no justification in taking the natural log of P when I'm trying to find the sum of P, but I'm not sure how to proceed as even without the natural log, the resulting function is too convoluted to integrate.

Comment: Hint:  You want to sum your $P(m)$ over the possible $m$.  Change variables so that you are summing over the possible $N_r$, as that runs from $0$ to $N$.  Your sum becomes $$\sum_{j=0}^N\binom {N}{j}p^j(1-p)^{n-j}=\left(p+(1-p)\right)^N$$

Comment: His name was Stirling.

Comment: Lulu, Is there a way to prove or explain that summation? It doesn't seem trivial to me. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: Actually I think I got it. I can use the binomial theorem on p and q to solve it

Answer (score 1):

Let $P_n(m)$ be the probability of reaching $m^{th}$ position at time $n$.

The proper way to attack this sort problem is not to compute any sum explicitly.
Instead, one should try to prove following sum over $m$ is independent of $n$.

$$\mathcal{S}_n \stackrel{def}{=}\sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty P_n(m)$$

The main reason is with minimal modification, the argument given below can make to work even when $p$ depends of $n$ or when the jumps in each time steps are not limited to the nearest neighbor. As long as the range of jumps at each time step 
is finite, for any fixed $n$, there are only finitely many $m$ when $P_n(m) \ne 0$. So above sums $\mathcal{S}_n$ are always well defined and you can manipulate
it like ordinary finite sum.

Back to the problem at hand, it is not hard to see our $P_n(m)$ satisfies a recurrence relation of the form

$$P_n(m) = p P_{n-1}(m-1) + (1-p) P_{n-1}(m+1)\quad\text{ for }n > 1$$
Summing over $m$ give us

$$\mathcal{S}_n = p \mathcal{S}_{n-1} + (1-p) \mathcal{S}_{n-1} =
(p + (1-p))\mathcal{S}_{n-1} = \mathcal{S}_{n-1}\quad\text{ for }n > 1$$

Since $\displaystyle\;P_0(m) = \begin{cases} 1,& m = 0\\ 0,& m \ne 0\end{cases},\;$ 
we have $\mathcal{S}_0 = 1$ and hence $\mathcal{S}_n = 1$ for all $n \ge 0$.

Answer (score 0):

You can model a random walk using the binomial theorem.  Model a single step as $px + \frac{1-p}{x}$, and $n$ steps as $\left(px + \frac{1-p}{x}\right)^n$.  The coefficient of $x^i$ is the probability that, after $n$ steps, the person is at position $i$ (assuming $l=1$).  From the binomial theorem,

$$\begin{align}
\left(px + \frac{1-p}{x}\right)^n & = \sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom{n}{i}((px)^i((1-p)x^{-1}))^{n-i})\\
& = \sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom{n}{i}p^ix^i(1-p)^{n-i}x^{i-n}\\
& =\sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom{n}{i}p^i(1-p)^{n-i}x^{2i-n}\\
\end{align}$$

So the probability that you wind up at position $2i-n$ is $\binom{n}{i}p^i(1-p)^{n-i}$.  The probability of all other positions is $0$.

As @lulu pointed out, the initial form (with $x=1$) gives you a trivial proof that the sum of all probabilities is $1$.